# Why timezone abbreviation for Asia/Kuala_Lumpur shows +8 instead of MYT?

Tags: php, date, timezone

So i'm trying to get timezone abbreviation from date with timezone `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur`, when e.g. I do:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'));
echo $dateTime->format('T');
```

is outputs +08, shouldn't it be `MYT`?

Comment: The docs for https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php say "Timezone abbreviation, **if known**; otherwise the GMT offset." Presumably it doesn't know MYT.

Comment: The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) that `T` will print _Timezone abbreviation, **if known**; otherwise the GMT offset. Examples: EST, MDT, +05_ . (My bold). So presumably PHP doesn't know the abbreviation for that timezone. Raise a ticket with the relevant developers if you think that should be corrected.

Answer (score 4):

The [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) source code/data can be seen in the maintainer's GitHub repository. The data for Asia/Kuala_Lumpur is [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/7f60edb1d696c8dc849b92c50b03ded536497b2c/asia#L2752) and uses "LMT", "SMT" and then numeric values for abbreviations.

```
Zone Asia/Kuala_Lumpur  6:46:46 -    LMT    1901 Jan  1
                        6:55:25 -    SMT    1905 Jun  1 # Singapore M.T.
                        7:00    -    +07    1933 Jan  1
                        7:00    0:20 +0720  1936 Jan  1
                        7:20    -    +0720  1941 Sep  1
                        7:30    -    +0730  1942 Feb 16
                        9:00    -    +09    1945 Sep 12
                        7:30    -    +0730  1982 Jan  1
                        8:00    -    +08
```

So PHP is doing the right thing in terms of propagating the time zone database information. Sometimes numbers are used for abbreviations if the maintainers are unaware of a well-accepted abbreviation. If you feel MYT would be correct here, I'd encourage you to post to the mailing list shown on the first link, ideally with sources of evidence. (I'm not doubting your knowledge for one second - just setting expectations that changes to the database require evidence.)